# algebra inequality question

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Let $x$ be a positive real number. Then show that for any $x$,
 $$x^2+\pi^2+x^{2\pi} \geq x^\pi(\pi+x)+x\pi.$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please put the brackets properly.

Comment: $$x^2+π^2+x^{2π}≥x^π(π+x)+xπ$$

Comment: this isn't linear algebra since you have the term $x^{2\pi}$. Do you want to prove the inequality for some $x$ you forgot to mention, or do you want to solve the inequation?

Comment: Try to regroup the terms that aren't linear and show us what you get. :)

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to mention. x be a positive real number and want to prove the inequality for any x.

Comment: Welcome. Edit your question. Show what you tried. The more effort you show, the more likely you are to get an answer.

Comment: Oh, and don't forget to vote up for answers that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : this try is wrong**
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. We have
$$\leqslant (-x^\pi + x + \pi)^2 = (x^{\pi})^2 + x^2 + \pi^2 - 2 x^\pi (x+\pi) \underbrace{-}_{\textbf{this should be +}} 2 x \pi $$
Bu $(x^\pi)^2 = x^{2\pi}$. Hence, 
$$x^{2\pi} + x^2 + \pi^2 \geqslant 2 \big(x^\pi(x + \pi) + x \pi\big) $$
Since the right hand term is positive, you get 
$$x^{2\pi} + x^2 + \pi^2 \geqslant x^\pi(x + \pi) + x \pi $$

**Edit : new attempt**
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, we have 
$$x^{2\pi} + x^2 + \pi^2 \geqslant x^\pi(x + \pi) + x \pi \Longleftrightarrow \\
x^{2\pi} + x^2 + \pi^2 - x^\pi(x + \pi) - x \pi \geqslant 0$$

Notice that
$$x^{2\pi} + x^2 + \pi^2 - x^\pi(x + \pi) - x \pi = \\
\underbrace{x^\pi(x^\pi + x + \pi)}_{\geqslant 0}  
+ \underbrace{x^2 + \pi^2 - x\pi}_{\geqslant (x - \pi)^2} \\ \geqslant 0$$

Whence the claim.

Comment: Check please your solution again.

Comment: it should be +2xπ instead of -2xπ.

Comment: Got some hint. As we know that for real values of a,b,c $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca≥0$$, so if we take $$a=x^π$$ , b=x, c=π then we can prove the same inequality. Is it correct?

Comment: @SajidAnwar That's more or less what I was trying to do. Yes it is correct.

Comment: Thankyou @OlivierRoche:)

Comment: @SajidAnwar Don't forget to upvote/mark answers you found helpful . ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(x-\pi\right)^2+\left(\pi-x^\pi\right)^2+\left(x^\pi-x\right)^2\ge 0\\x^2-2\pi x+\pi^2+\pi^2-2\pi x^\pi+x^{2\pi}+x^{2\pi}-2x^{\pi+1}+x^2\ge0\\2x^2+2\pi^2+2x^{2\pi}\ge2x^\pi\left(x+\pi\right)+2x\pi \\x^2+\pi^2+x^{2\pi}\ge x^\pi\left(x+\pi\right)+x\pi$$